# how to List double values from dynamically added EditTexts android

Tags: android, math, android-edittext, double

I want to create a list of the double values. [screen shot of my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPRU0.png)

When the (+) add button is pressed a minimum of three edit boxes are added.
i want to get the values of these edit boxes and be able to cross multiply them.
the values will be mostly +/- and with decimals.

How can i identify  the edit boxes, then from the input Values, i set them in a List where i can be able to cross Multiply them.

I am trying this but i don't understand where am going wrong.

```
List<EditText> allNs = new ArrayList<EditText>();
List<EditText> allEs = new ArrayList<EditText>();
String[] northings = new String[allNs.size()];
String[] eastings = new String[allEs.size()];
double inputNorths, inputEasts = 0; 

for(int i=0; i<allNs.size(); i++){
    northings[i] = allNs.get(i).getText().toString();
    inputNorths = Double.parseDouble(northings[i]);
    northValues [1] = inputNorths;
}

resultN.add(northValues);

for(int e=0; e<allEs.size(); e++){
    eastings[e] = allEs.get(e).getText().toString();
    inputEasts = Double.parseDouble(eastings[e]);
    eastValues[2] = inputEasts;
}

resultsE.add(eastValues);
calcArea();
```

Comment: _"... but i don't understand where am going wrong."_ So, what's the problem? What errors did you get?

Comment: Wouldn't `northings` and `eastings` just have a size of `0`, as their sizes are based on empty `ArrayList`s?

Comment: Am new to programming, was following a tutorial.  I put the one and 2 in the northings[1] and Eastings[2] trying to understand how the code would select when calculating. But the result was 0.

For the parseDouble(northing[i]) ; and parseDouble(eastings[e]) ; am trying to have two Lists one for Northings and another for Eastings.   The formulae am trying to use is like N1E2+N2E3+N3E1-E1N2+E2N3+E3N1=2A

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I don't understand what are you doing here:

```
inputNorths = Double.parseDouble(northings[i]);
....
inputEasts = Double.parseDouble(eastings[e]);
```

Every loop you overwrite these variables. Maybe you forgot about adding?

```
    inputNorths += Double.parseDouble(northings[i]);
northValues [1] += inputNorths;
```